# How to implement a ilike Facebook system without user authentication and still prevent users from cheating?

Tags: java, facebook, grails

I am trying to implement something done in almost any website out there : **a 'ilike' button** (like Facebook) **that does not require user authetication** to be used for any article of my website written in Grails.

I don't want to use any external solution, so I need to implement it myself (or use a grails plugin).

So my question is : What does it take to implement this 'ilike' button and **prevent users from cheating at the maximum**? For instance, do I need to store local cookies (I suppose yes)? Do I need to check the session ID and IP of the HTTP request?

What are the **well-known implementations for online polls for instance**?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: User can do anything to cheat. It's possible to do without authentication but cannot prevent at maximum. User can delete cookies, change ip address, change browser & etc..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No user authentication** and **completely** prevent cheating? No can do, sorry.

You could restrict casting votes per IP address, but NATs and proxies and VPNs make this unworkable (an IP address could map to many users - e.g. a school or a municipal network, a user could map to many IP addresses - e.g. mobile connection or DHCP, etc).

You could set a cookie, but these can be deleted, or not even stored, very easily (Ctrl+Shift+Del, anyone?).

Note that just **by setting a cookie, you'll prevent 90% of the users from cheating** (less if your site has a technical, web-savvy audience); alas, if you don't have some way of identifying the users (e.g. by authentication), there is no way to avoid cheating altogether (and even then people would create sockpuppets to up their vote counts).

Facebook's "like" button is something very different - it **appears** to use no authentication, but actually it requires you to be logged into FB - thus FB stores the vote counts in the database, against usert IDs - and knows which user voted on what, preventing most of voter fraud.

Example - a table of "who voted on what":

```
user_id | article_id
1234         1
1234         5
1100         1
```

Without the user ID, you'd need to set up some anonymous ID. As I have outlined above, this can be done, but every time the user deletes their cookies, he will appear as a completely new user to the system. Since sessions are implemented *using* cookies, this same problem applies to sessions, too.

If you absolutely need to allow anonymous voting, you could store in the session a list of articles this user voted on:

```
{ 1, 5 }
```

and check it when the page is accessed. If you set your cookie and session expirations for long enough, this will sort-of work - but again, once the user clears their cookies (or they expire), *bamf* he's gone and will look as a new user. There is no way to prevent this, using current technologies (yes, there are "persistent cookies","flash cookies","evercookies" and whatnot, but they are, in the end, all just some sort of temporary storage the user can erase).

Comment: Thx for your answer. I update my question to make it more precise

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful answer. What about Request IP? I mean, preventing same IP from voting twice?

Comment: @fabien7474: Not reliable, too many false positives - due to NATing, there could be 1000s of users behind any one IP address (and since the IPv4 pool is running out, this will only get worse); also too many false negatives - due to proxies and VPNs and accelerators, a user could be coming in from several different addresses. Combined with the cookies, it's a useful heuristic, but not an absolute measure.